# XML searching line by line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have an XML doc with the following format:

```
<document>
  <page>
    <column>
      <text>
        <par>
          <line></line>
        </par>
      </text>
    </column>
  </page>
</document>
```

I want to search for a string in the XML, but might be in multiple line tags, multiple block docs, and/or multiple page tags:

```
<document>
  <page>
    <column>
      <text>
        <par>
          <line>Hello</line>
        </par>
      </text>
    </column>
    <column>
      <text>
        <par>
          <line>World</line>
        </par>
      </text>
    </column>
  </page>
  <page>
    <column>
      <text>
        <par>
          <line>What's</line>
          <line>Up?</line>
        </par>
      </text>
    </column>
  </page>
</document>
```

I need to search for "Hello World What's Up?" and know that it's on line 1 of column 1, line 1 of column 2, and lines 1-2 of block 3 (page 3 block 1).

I have metadata on the lines to tell me what line number it is, along with what column number it belongs to, for example:

```
<line linenum="1" columnnum="2">World</line>
```

What would be the best way to search for that term across different columns, and be able to know the details of what lines and columns they belong to?

I can get all instances of the first word, iterate on each and see if the following words correspond to the search words (word by word), and if there aren't any more words in that line, go to the next line. If there aren't anymore lines, go to the next block. Thoughts?

Here's a real snippet of an example XML code, and what the script is returning:

```
<block>
  <text>
    <par>
      <line colnum="1" linenum="1">
        (12) United States Patent
      </line>
    </par>
    <par>
      <line colnum="1" linenum="2">
        Kar-Roy et al.
      </line>
    </par>
  </text>
</block>
<block>
  <text>
    <par>
      <line colnum="2" linenum="3">
        US007078310B1
      </line>
    </par>
  </text>
</block>
<block>
  <text>
    <par>
      <line colnum="3" linenum="4">
        (io) Patent No.: US 7,078,310 B1
      </line>
    </par>
    <par>
      <line colnum="3" linenum="5">
        (45) Date of Patent: Jul. 18,2006
      </line>
    </par>
  </text>
</block>
<block>
  <text>
    <par>
      <line>
        (54) METHOD FOR FABRICATING A HIGH
      </line>
      <line>
        DENSITY COMPOSITE MIM CAPACITOR
      </line>
    </par>
  </text>
</block>
```

When I search for "METHOD FOR FABRICATING A HIGH", `map{|f| f.text}` returns:

```
["Kar-Roy et al.", "US007078310B1", "(io) Patent No.: US 7,078,310 B1", "(45) Date of Patent: Jul. 18,2006", "(54) METHOD FOR FABRICATING A HIGH"]
```

It looks like it's taking the five-word length, and getting the four lines before the actual result for some reason.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have metadata in the `<line>` tags, then why don't you show us that? It's important when providing data that it be minimized to avoid overload, but still it has to be accurate for the information needed.

Comment: Metadata has been added, and I've actually been here for a couple of years, but thanks for the warm welcome @the-tin-man !

Comment: @JordanMichaelRushing Where did you get the patent XML with column and line numbers?  I have been looking for a source of USPTO machine-readable patent text that has the columns/lines marked and have been thinking I would have to process the OCR text on my own --- but this makes me think maybe I don't!

Comment: @cxw I *think* I got this from a PDF OCR company's trial (super expensive so didn't end up using them long term). This is an ongoing problem for my company (production on this side has halted so if you can figure out a solution for this PLEASE let me know).

Comment: @JordanMichaelRushing :( Any way I can get in touch with you off-site if I come up with something (or vice versa ;) )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my thought: first, parse your structure into an XML parser like Nokogiri, and then use an XPath search to extract all the `line` elements. Then, break each element into the words contained in that node, so we can match on phrases which only match part of a node. Then, order the words consecutively, use `each_cons(4)` (where `4` is the number of words you're searching for) to look at all consecutive sets of four words, and return if they match your search string when concatenated. Here's my code to do so:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML.parse(doc)

search = "HIGH DENSITY"

# 1. break down all the lines into words tagged with their nodes
# 2. find matching subsequence
# 3. build up from nodes

nodes = xml.xpath('//line')
words = nodes.map do |n|
  words_in_node = n.text.split(' ').map(&:upcase) # split into words and normalize
  words_in_node.map { |word| { word: word, node: n } }
end
words = words.flatten # at this point we have a single, ordered list like [ {word: "foo", node: ...}, {word: "bar", node: ...} ]

keywords = search.split(' ').map(&:upcase)
result = words.each_cons(keywords.size).find do |sample|
  # Extract just the :word key from each hash, then compare to our search string
  sample_words = sample.map { |w| w[:word] }
  sample_words == keywords
end

if result
  puts "Found in these nodes:"
  puts result.map { |w| w[:node] }.uniq.inspect
  # you can find where each node was located via Nokogiri
else
  puts "No match"
end
```

Which produces:

```
Found in these nodes:
[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x4ea323e name="line" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x4ea294c "\n        (54) METHOD FOR FABRICATING A HIGH\n      ">]>,
 #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x4ea3018 name="line" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x4ea2654 "\n        DENSITY COMPOSITE MIM CAPACITOR\n      ">]>]
```

Comment: So this is absolutely gorgeous. Just one little hiccup. In the real xml doc each line could have multiple words in it.so the strip and join on kws isn't making the all of the white space disappear, so I added a gsub to it. That's returning lines, but there's a second issue.

It's returning (words.size - actual returned results) results in the results array. I'll add an edit to the question so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Ok, question has been updated. Thanks again Robert for your killer help!

Comment: See my edited version. I didn't have time to test it on your actual sample, so there may be bugs, but it worked on a simplified example locally.

Comment: So there was one small bug where text can't be called on nil, so I changed the first line of the method to `return [] if string == "" || nodes[0].nil?`

However now I'm not getting anything back. I tried to check on what should be one of the regex checks, and it's returning nil (rightfully so).

search = "METHODFORFABRICATINGAHIGHDENSITY"
pattern = /^\(54\)METHODFORFABRICATINGAHIGH/i

Which will return nil. Note "DENSITY" is in the line after 'method for fabricating a high'

Comment: Okay, I see why. The first selected node has to end with the portion of the string, and any node after that which doesn't finish the string needs to both start and end with the next portion of the string, and the last node just needs to start with it. I'll take a look tomorrow at handling those edge cases, or you can take a stab at it. There might be a simpler solution I'm missing.

Comment: Well I ended up checking back into your first example code and was able to hack that in combo with a set of ruby code. But I'm not a big fan of how I implemented it, and feel it would be kind of slow. If you have any ideas to catch that kind of outlier, I'm all ears.

Comment: @JordanMichaelRushing after some thought, I went back to my original solution but added the extra step of breaking each node down into a list of the words in that node. It can't handle partial-word matches, though; in that case, you'd need to break each node down into a list of characters. Or do this in some other way :)

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much Robert, seriously you rock!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want, I'd go about it like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<document>
  <page>
    <column>
      <text>
        <par>
          <line linenum="1" columnnum="1">Hello</line>
        </par>
      </text>
    </column>
    <column>
      <text>
        <par>
          <line linenum="1" columnnum="2">World</line>
        </par>
      </text>
    </column>
  </page>
  <page>
    <column>
      <text>
        <par>
          <line linenum="1" columnnum="3">What's</line>
          <line linenum="2" columnnum="3">Up?</line>
        </par>
      </text>
    </column>
  </page>
</document>
EOT

line_text = doc.search('column').map { |column| 
  column.search('line').map{ |line|
    {
      line: line['linenum'],
      column: line['columnnum'],
      text: line.text
    }
  }
}
```

At this point `line_text` contains:

```
line_text 
# => [[{:line=>"1", :column=>"1", :text=>"Hello"}],
#     [{:line=>"1", :column=>"2", :text=>"World"}],
#     [{:line=>"1", :column=>"3", :text=>"What's"},
#      {:line=>"2", :column=>"3", :text=>"Up?"}]]
```

This is grouping by `<column>`. The metadata isn't necessary, but it's convenient if it exists in the XML. If it doesn't, remove the lines to capture those parameters and only return the text:

```
line_text = doc.search('column').map { |column| 
  column.search('line').map{ |line|
    line.text
  }
}

line_text 
# => [["Hello"], ["World"], ["What's", "Up?"]]
```

`line_text` is now an array of arrays. Each element in the outer array signifies a column, and the elements inside that sub-array are the lines, so you could keep track of things that way with a much smaller returned array along with a bit of extra code:

```
line_text.each.with_index(1) do |column, column_num|
  column.each.with_index(1) do |text, line_num|
    puts "column: #{column_num} line: #{line_num} text: #{text}"
  end
end
# >> column: 1 line: 1 text: Hello
# >> column: 2 line: 1 text: World
# >> column: 3 line: 1 text: What's
# >> column: 3 line: 2 text: Up?
```